# Dependent Template Compiles with Visual Studio, but fails with clang/gcc

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The following code compiles under Visual Studio 2013, and fails to compile under gcc/clang (all tested versions).

clang: `error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'write' as a dependent template name`

gcc: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’`

Both errors occur where indicated in the code

```
template <typename Itr>    
struct A {        
    template <typename Other>    
    void write(Other x) {}    
};      

template <class T>    
struct B {       
   A<T>& a;    
   B(A<T>& a) : a(a) {    
      // error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'write' as a dependent template name    
      a.write<int>(5);    
   }    
}; 

int main() {    
    A<int> a;    
    // Fine    
    a.write<int>(5);    
    B<int> b(a);    
}
```

Experience tells me that Visual Studio is probably wrong, but I'm not sure why this should fail to compile when `A<T>` is fully specified, and I'm only wanting to call a template method whose type I specify.

Comment: I see this is marked as a duplicate, and yeah, it technically is.. But surely you can understand how a person managed to make this mistake when you need to understand the standard's very technical wording to make that connection. Also from the examples in that question, it isn't immediately clear that this is related. I personally think this is a useful question, but whatever.

Comment: A question being marked a duplicate isn't a negative reflection on the question. This question is perfectly fine. It's just that it's been asked before, and the linked question has a very thorough explanation of the problem and the solution. Duplicates stay alive forever to be used as signposts. Closed questions are deleted.

Comment: @Barry Ah, right! Good to know, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [temp.names], emphasis mine:

> When the **name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression*** or after a
>   *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and **the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is *type-dependent***
>   or the *nested-name-specifier* in the *qualified-id* refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of
>   the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name **must be prefixed by the keyword `template`**.
>   Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

Here, `write` is a member template specialization that appears after a `.` in a *postfix-expression*, and `a` is *type-dependent* (it depends on `T`), and `a` is not a member of the current instantiation (which would be `B<T>`), so it must be prefixed with `template`. gcc and clang are correct to reject this code, as it should be treated as if `write` were a non-template and the `<` were an operator - which is invalid.

Comment: Great, thanks. I really need to improve my standard searching skills. Is it just me or does the correct version, `a.template write<int>(5)` look incredibly... weird?

Comment: @user3870920 It is what it is.

Comment: C++ gets more and more obscure the more they try to make template work. My approach: Use templates conservatively and stick to "c with classes" - c++ :)